# tipo de dato que no omita el valor 0 en base de datos sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el código de postal de Alicante 03004. He asignado diferentes tipos de valores numericos pero todos me quitan el 0 de delante. Lo que quiero es que aparezca **03004** y no 3004 como aparece ahora. Versión del servidor: 5.5.62 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Es que por más que haya números, ese dato debe manejarse como una cadena

Comment: El código postal no se suma, no se resta, no se multiplica. No es un número que se opere sino una cadena (String) que se representa tal cual es. A los tipos numéricos no les gustan los ceros a la izquierda :)

Comment: Además de lo ya dicho, ¿Qué va a pasar el día que se les ocurra incluir un guión, o una letra en el código postal? [Argentina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_Postal_Argentino), [Canadá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada), [Irlanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_addresses_in_the_Republic_of_Ireland), [Paises bajos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_the_Netherlands) y otros utilizan letras dentro del código postal.

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de datos es `VAR` o `VARCHAR`.
Primero, la columna debe tener este tipo:

```
ALTER TABLE direcciones MODIFY codigo_postal CHAR(5) ZEROFILL;
```

En segundo lugar, cuando inserta un código postal en una tabla con un cero inicial:

```
INSERT INTO direcciones (codigo_postal) VALUES ('03004');
```

Al insertar, puede usar `CASE`, que verifica la cantidad de caracteres y agrega la cantidad requerida de ceros.
Algo como:

```
CASE
    WHEN codigo_postal >= 10000 THEN CAST(codigo_postal as VARCHAR(5))
    WHEN codigo_postal >= 1000 THEN CONCAT('0', CAST(codigo_postal as VARCHAR(4))
    WHEN codigo_postal >= 100 THEN CONCAT('00', CAST(codigo_postal as VARCHAR(3))
    WHEN codigo_postal >= 10 THEN CONCAT('000', CAST(codigo_postal as VARCHAR(2))
    WHEN codigo_postal >= 1 THEN CONCAT('0000', CAST(codigo_postal as VARCHAR(1))
    ELSE 'desconocido'
END;
```

Comment: es mejor dar respuestas que no necesiten aclaracion, en este caso por ejemplo.... como verificar la cantidad de caracteres con un CASE y agrega la cantidad requerida de ceros

Comment: He agregado el código de CASE a la respuesta principal

Comment: se ve bien la respuesta, solo hay que cuidar los tipos de datos, el char es de longitud fija, entonces, si creas un char(5) y le guardas"1" guarda "1    " y puede causar problemas a hacer las comparaciones.
para este ejemplo del código postal no debería haber problema, pero, hay que tenerlo en cuenta